# FPE 24 Breaker Panel Swap

Tags: electrical

I need to change out my old FPE panel which is a Stab Loc type 100 amp panel with 24 positions.  Does anyone have any panel recommendations that are roughly the same size as my existing FPE panel.

Changed by adding photos... FYI I am on a ship floating in the middle of the Gulf of Mexico so I can't actually go home and measure the panel, my sincerest apologies for not adding photos initially.

Some other details that may be relevant.. I'm not looking for an exact fit, I am sure I will need to tear out some sheetrock and repair at a later date but I was interested in something roughly the same size.

The existing location is in my hobby room and the panel is on the wall in a suitable location meeting all the requirements in NEC 110.26.

There isn't any need for a much larger panel as this is a sub panel inside the house only serving lights, outlets etc.. all the heavy hitters are in the main service panel on the exterior of the house.

I'm very keen on Square D QO panels unless you can talk me out of it... I'll be installing combo's for any required areas per 210.8 and 210.12.

Anyway.. thanks for any helpful ideas or lessons.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Roughly" doesn't always work. Can you measure (a) the actual space in use (width and height) and (b) how much space is available (width likely, but not necessarily, the same, height may be significantly more). Also keep in mind that if there is not sufficient working space in front of the panel then other changes might be needed because for a new panel it is likely that the working space requirements will be enforced.

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel as well as the width and height of the existing panel enclosure please?

Comment: Product recommendations are Off Topic here. You just need to do your own research on panel sizes in various brands.

Comment: So you're on a ship in the Gulf of Mexico.... what the heck are you doing on this site. Worry about this when you get home.

Comment: I'm not worried about it.. had some free time and thought I would post something up.

Answer (score 1):

### Forget about "same size"

The rules back then on panel size were very slack.  Some makers (FPE particularly) made very compact panels.

Since then, NEC and UL rules have tightened up, mainly relating to *wire bending space*, an issue often ignored back then.  Also, any modern builder of a >= 24 space panel will certainly be expecting it to be fed from a 200A service, and 200A wires require *even more* bending space.

The gold standard for panel width these days is **14-1/4"**, just the right size to fit between joists on 16" standard centers.  That is going to be your width on *any panel on the market*.

As for height, heights are now much greater.  Almost any 24-space or larger will be a "convertible", meaning it has several inches of height reserved for retrofitting a main breaker.

### The existing location may not work

Not to add to your headaches, but Code also now requires accessible locations for panels.  There must be flat ground and a 30x36" working space in front of the panel **that is kept clear at ALL times**. Rather than be the "box police", the best plan is to place the panel in an area that will be kept clear *anyway* because it is a pathway, like a hallway or threshold.

However, the old panel can be kept with its breaker slots blanked over, and used as a giant junction box to extend circuits to a new location.

### Since you can't go small, go big

Houses use *less* power in some ways (more efficient lighting and A/C), modern life has an unbelievable appetite for **breaker spaces** since we simply have more gadgets today, and many take dedicated circuits.  Surge suppressor needs 2, many people are getting generator hookups which takes 2-6 spaces, solar takes 2, electric vehicle takes 2, on and on we go.

You go through spaces like water.

Since squeezing it into the available space is a lost cause, you might as well go for a large size panel e.g. a 40-space panel.  If your house required 24 spaces *back in the day when FPE panels were being installed*, probably even 40 spaces is not enough by modern standards.  You might consider dual 30's.

[image]

*Not anymore*.